# Is There an rNPV Model Relating Money Supply, Total Wealth and Money Velocity?

Tags: money-supply, risk-aversion, wealth, quantity-theory-of-money, liquidity

It seems sensible that the supply of constant-value units of [fiat money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat_money) should roughly correspond to the total wealth of the jurisdiction's economy, in the same sense that an on-demand gold certificate should correspond to a unit of gold secured in a vault.

[The risk adjusted Net Present Value calculation (rNPV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNPV) is a widely accepted method of measuring the wealth represented by an asset.

The rNPV estimates the [velocity of money](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/32242), as profit, through the asset being valued in such a manner that it approximates the liquidation value.

Other money flows ([flow is probably a better metaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_rate)) through the asset ([OPEX and CAPEX](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/112814/whats-difference-between-capital-expenditures-capex-and-operational-expenditures-opex.asp)) appear in the rNPV of other assets in the economy.

Therefore it seems reasonable to to expect that there must have been attempts to model the relationship between money supply, total wealth and money velocity in terms of rNPV.

Does such a model exist?  What are its main weaknesses (other than the efficient market hypothesis)?